# "no provider" for custom validation directive Angular 6 template-driven form?

Tags: angular, forms

I'm following the documentation at https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

I've added a directive to my project using ng generate

```
import { Directive} from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appForbiddenRisInternalIdValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: 'ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective', multi: true}]

})
export class ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    console.log('Validating');
    return null;
  }

}
```

That also added it to my app.module.ts, as I would have expected.

```
 import { ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective } from './validators/forbidden-ris-internal-id-validator.directive';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   ..........,
    ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective
  ],
```

The documentation now just says to make this work, I just have to add the selector to the form, and that the provider part of the directive will add this validator to the list of validators that will be run on my form.

I've tried it in my form tag.

```
<form #RBoxAddEdit='ngForm' (submit)='updateBox(RBoxAddEdit)' appForbiddenRisInternalIdValidator>
```

I've also tried it directly in the input I'm trying to add the validation to.

```
 <input appForbiddenRisInternalIdValidator #customValidation = 'ngModel' maxlength="45" id="risinternalId"  name="risnternalId" matInput  required [(ngModel)]='boxEdit.risinternalId' placeholder="RIS ID (RBXXXX)">
```

However, no matter where I add it, I get a null injector error.

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective!
```

It seems like I'm missing something. Any idea what I missed?

Answer (score 2):

The value to `useExisting` field should be a token instead of a `string`.

Try changing this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appForbiddenRisInternalIdValidator]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: 'ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective',
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective implements Validator { ...
}
```

to this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appForbiddenRisInternalIdValidator]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class ForbiddenRisInternalIdValidatorDirective implements Validator { ...
}
```

Without `''`

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-template-driven-form-validator?file=src/app/forbidden-ris-internal-id-validator.directive.ts) for your ref.